# Alarms app not working (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, notifications

I used the built-in Microsoft Alarms app regularly. Normally a small notification appears in the upper right and the alarm chimes.

But recently it has stopped working. The notification does not appear in the upper right and the chime does not go off. I've not knowingly modified any system settings and the volume is definitely working (have listened to music multiple times).

When I set up an alarm, a banner is displayed at the top of the screen which says `Notifications will only appear if the PC is awake`. My PC is on and I am working on it when I expect the alarm to go off, so this may not be important but I mention it in case this is relevant.

What might be causing the Alarms application to stop working?

Comment: Have you rebooted the pc at least once since this problem started to occur?

Comment: Yes, several times